# Webpack переименовывает переменные при импорте

Tags: javascript, webpack

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

**tab.js содержит такие данные:**

```
let qwerty = 'qwerty'
```

**scripts.js содержит:**

```
'use strict';
import 'tab.js'

console.log('qwerty', qwerty);
```

В результате на странице выводится ошибка:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: qwerty is not defined
```

Глянул в скомпилированный файл и вижу такое:

```
'use strict';
let tab_qwerty = 'qwerty';
console.log('qwerty', qwerty);
```

Получается при компиляции вебпак переименовывает переменную **qwerty** в **tab_qwerty**, таким образом переменную, которую я хочу получить недоступна.
Как быть наведите на мысль?

Comment: Написав строку `import 'tab.js'` вы не импортировали ни одной переменной из файла tab.js в файл script.js, поэтому webpack имеет полное правильно переименовывать что угодно как он хочет.

Comment: Более того, скрипт `tab.js` не экспортирует ни одну переменную (отсутствует `export` или `module.exports`), поэтому импортировать переменные из вашего `tab.js` в принципе невозможно. Думаю, вам нужно почитать учебники про работу модулей в javascript https://learn.javascript.ru/modules

Comment: Искренне благодарю. Очень помогли!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем нужно было очень внимательно прочесть три статьи https://learn.javascript.ru/modules

**tab.js**

```
export let qwerty = 'qwerty'
```

**scripts.js**

```
import {qwerty} from 'tab.js'
```

Благодарю andreymal